# Trying to decrypt a password stored in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, asp.net, encryption, passwords

I have a customer I'm trying to convert their current user system to Asp.Net.  I have the current database. The preferred solution would be to import the current data and have it work without actually having to figure out the passwords and re-add all of the users.  In the database the user info the info I have is as follows:

(this is a test user)

```
username: pixelrazor
password:d5f916bb8d603a8db3300337e0af02e41a3e496aea850efd621bcfe6bbf4c210c634e5d8a298419eee504cb8875e6545bb79f3a6c1a8c9c8fa7482e74bf48b86
salt:NVzjxi#U+2nZqB"u!9^O<6@UZY$2%5doY[:obpNh<7?P:Bt>rm.O_r}O"X3[eEGP/fo0,U;D:drBea1x%zW8"G@l?M;yX~t+=f~.x8Q!11Ymr?%0eCY$ty(sl./'CwZD
uniquekey: be6727dbd1c2755d1ac887c770d34c9f1f3a65bd
crypt-key:fc3b8255ff0a719d0c2074adb949b73fee636776
```

(the unhashed or encrypted password is `abcd1234`)

Is there any way to figure out what type of security this password has?  It's from expressionengine, using a mysql database.

This is just a little out of my sphere any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I think uniqueKey is kind of signature and key is real-key to decrypt the password. Try applying Cipher using SecretKey.

Answer (score 0):

See [this post that talks about EE encrytpion](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/197218/#930156). The key section is

E 2.x has introduced environment-sensitive hash algorithms and password salts—both good things! And the code in system/expressionengine/libraries/Auth.php (as of ExpressionEngine 2.2.2) seems simple enough:

1. Fetch `exp_members.salt` and `exp_members.password` for the user
2. Choose a hash algorithm based on the byte length of `exp_members.password` (hopefully this is 128 bytes, which corresponds to SHA-512!)
3. Concatenate `exp_members.salt` and user’s password input (in that order, e.g. $salt.$password)
4. Hash the resulting string using the algorithm chosen in step two
5. Compare the hashed string and `exp_members.password`

Note that they also refer to the [PHP source code.](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/45121933/) that has the auth functions. The rest is up to you since I don't claim to PHP.